# how to Replace color in attributed string in objective c

Tags: objective-c, nsattributedstring

in my attributed string there is multiple colors. like Red,black,green Colors

here is sample string

[image]

in this string,I want to replace all red color words into yellow Color.

can anyone please guide me how can i achive this ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to enumerate the NSAttributedString and change the value of the attribute when condition is met.

Text Color attribute is done with `NSForegroundColorAttributeName`.
`attr` is the `NSMutableAttributedString` corresponding to yours.

```
//Retrieve the current attributedText. You need to make it mutable.
NSMutableAttributedString *attr = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithAttributedString:yourLabelOrTextView.attributedText]; 

[attr enumerateAttribute:NSForegroundColorAttributeName
                 inRange:NSMakeRange(0, [attr length]) options:0
              usingBlock:^(id  _Nullable value, NSRange range, BOOL * _Nonnull stop) {
                  if ([value isKindOfClass:[UIColor class]]) //Check just in case that the value is really a UIColor
                  {
                      UIColor *currentColor = (UIColor *)value;
                      if ([currentColor isEqual:[UIColor redColor]]) //Condition
                      {
                          [attr addAttribute:NSForegroundColorAttributeName
                                       value:[UIColor yellowColor]
                                       range:range];
                      }
                  }
              }];
[yourLabelOrTextView setAttributedText:attr]; //Replace the previous attributedText on UI with the new one.
```

You could remove the previous color (red) and then apply the new one, but since there is a unicity you don't have to, it will replace it.

Comment: Crashing app. . . . 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[NSConcreteAttributedString addAttribute:value:range:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance

Comment: "attr is the NSMutableAttributedString corresponding to yours." NS**Mutable**AttributedString, The NSAttributedString has to be **mutable** in order to modify it. So `NSMutableAttributedString *attr = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithAttributedString:yourAttributedString];` at the end: `yourTextVieworLabel.attributedText = attr;`

Comment: Larme... yes iknow, i am using  NSMutableAttributedString ,

Comment: If you do textView.attributedText = myMutableAttributedString; NSMutableAttributedString * attr = textView.attributedText; attr will be not mutable.